# What's the difference between @ViewChild and @ContentChild?

Tags: angular

Angular 2 provides `@ViewChild`, `@ViewChildren`, `@ContentChild` and `@ContentChildren` decorators for querying a component's descendant elements.

What's the difference between the first two and the latter two?

Comment: This link helped me http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/01/23/angular2-viewchildren-contentchildren-difference-viewproviders/ after reading the below answers. Cheers :)

Answer (score 353, accepted):

I'll answer your question using **Shadow DOM** and **Light DOM** terminology (it have come from web components, see more [here](https://www.webcomponents.org/polyfills/shadow-dom/)). In general:

- ***Shadow DOM*** - is an internal DOM of your component that is defined **by you** (as a **creator of the component**) and hidden from an end-user. For example:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  template: `
    <h1>I am Shadow DOM!</h1>
    <h2>Nice to meet you :)</h2>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `;
})
class SomeComponent { /* ... */ }
```

- ***Light DOM*** - is a DOM that **an end-user of your component** supply into your component. For example:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'another-component',
  directives: [SomeComponent],
  template: `
    <some-component>
      <h1>Hi! I am Light DOM!</h1>
      <h2>So happy to see you!</h2>
    </some-component>
  `
})
class AnotherComponent { /* ... */ }
```

So, the answer to your question is pretty simple:

> The difference between `@ViewChildren` and `@ContentChildren` is that `@ViewChildren` look for elements in Shadow DOM while `@ContentChildren` look for them in Light DOM.

Comment: The blog entry http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/01/23/angular2-viewchildren-contentchildren-difference-viewproviders/ from Minko Gechew makes more sense to me. @ContentChildren are the children, inserted by content projection (the children between <ng-content></ng-content> ) . From Minkos Blog: "On the other hand, **elements which are used between the opening and closing tags of the host element of a given component are called *content children **."
Shadow DOM and view encapsulation in Angular2 is descibed here: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html .

Comment: To me it sounds like `@TemplateChildren` (instead of `@ViewChildren`) or  `@HostChildren` (instead of `@ContentChildren`) would have been much better names, as in such a context everything we're talking about is view-related, and w.r.t. binding is content-related too.

Comment: `@ViewChildren` == your own child ; `@ContentChildren` == someone's else child

Comment: @candidJ this is False today, in ContentChildren you have a flag that is {descendants: false} by default. So the equivalence is not correct.

Comment: What about the **@ViewChild** and **@ContentChild**?

Comment: @ContentChild looks the HTML defined in the use of your component tag, ex `<my-component><div>THIS IS CONTENT CHILD</div></my-component>`

Answer (score 169):

As the name suggests, `@ContentChild` and `@ContentChildren` queries will return directives existing inside the `<ng-content></ng-content>` element of your view, whereas `@ViewChild` and `@ViewChildren` only look at elements that are on your view template directly.

Comment: So use @ViewChild(ren) unless you have components in your view in which case fall back to @ContentChild(ren)?

Answer (score 54):

This video from Angular Connect has excellent info about ViewChildren, ViewChild, ContentChildren and ContentChild
https://youtu.be/4YmnbGoh49U

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <my-widget>
      <comp-a/>
    </my-widget>
`
})
class App {}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-widget',
  template: `<comp-b/>`
})
class MyWidget {}
```

From `my-widget`'s perspective, `comp-a` is the `ContentChild` and `comp-b` is the `ViewChild`. `CompomentChildren` and `ViewChildren` return an iterable while the xChild return a single instance.

Comment: This is the better explanation. Thanks :)

Comment: You made a clear and simple example, but MyWidget's template should be 
`<comp-b><ng-content></ng-content></comp-b>`
right?

Answer (score 16):

Lets take a example, We have one home component and one child component and inside child component one small child component.

```
<home>
     <child>
           <small-child><small-child>
     </child>
</home>
```

Now you can grab all children elements in context of home component with @viewChildren because these are directly added in template of home component.
But, when you try to access `<small-child>` element from context of child component then you can't access it because it is not directly added within child component template.
It is added through content projection into child component by home component.
This is where @contentChild comes in and you can grab it with @contentChild.

The difference occur when you try to access elements reference in controller.
You can grab all elements that are directly added into template of component by @viewChild.
But you can't grab projected elements reference with @viewChild
To access projected element you have to use @contentChild.

Answer (score 6):

Just rename ViewChildren to InternalChildren, and ContentChildren to ExternalChildren