# How to resize a DOM element at run time

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

In Angular 2 project, I am trying to resize a DOM element that I retrieve by id. 
I set the size as listed below and I don't observe any change.
What step am I missing?

```
        document.getElementById('my_grid').setAttribute("style","height:600px");
```

Comment: What kind of element is this you want to set the height for?

Comment: this is an angular 2 component

Answer (score 2):

Don't use like this. You can use angular 2 feature.

1. You can use `[style.height.px]="modelvalue"`
2. Second way, you can use `<div #mydiv>` in html and use @ViewChild in component

Example

```
@ViewChild mydiv;

resizeDiv() {
    this.mydiv.nativeElement...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the height to a `<div>` element. Your browser won't interpret the `height` attribute on an Angular directive.

Furthermore, the prefered way to access elements in your DOM is via the @ViewChild decorator. See [accessing native elements in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35463642/whats-the-proper-way-of-accessing-native-element-in-angular2-2-diff-ways-docs)

Answer (score 0):

In angular 2 whenever possible never use core javascript or jquery code to manipulate dom element. Try first with do angular 2 features.

We can use `[style.height.px]="height"` and whenever you want to change div height change height value from component