# Call the component dynamically angular2, attaching customElement to DOM onClick

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am trying to attach the element to parent DOM onClick. how to call the component dynamically?
If I add simple " hello  world , it works as expected. but I want to call the "myCustomTag" component.

Note: If I add "myCustomTag tag" directly in the template, it works. It is attaching the "myCustomTag" template as expected.

```
     @Component({
      selector: 'myTag',
      template: `<div (click) = "onAttachClick()"> clickToAddELement </div>`
    })
    export class xxx {
     getNewElement() {
         return '<myCustomTag [name]="someText"></myCustomTag>'
        }
        //on click, I need to add the element
        onAttachClick() {
       this.parentElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',this.getNewElement());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a local variable in

```
<div #myAttach (click) = "onAttachClick()"> clickToAddELement </div>
```

And use

```
export class xxx {
   @ViewChild('myAttach') myAttach;
   ....
}
```

then

```
this.myAttach.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',this.getNewElement());
```

Reading this might help you:
[What's the proper way of accessing native element in angular2 (2 diff ways) docs are scarce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35463642/whats-the-proper-way-of-accessing-native-element-in-angular2-2-diff-ways-docs)

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the reply. Attaching an element is fine.. But I was unable to call "mycustamtag" component .. It is attaching empty html element to the parent. Some how I want to call "mycomponent" with the <mycustomtag> html

Comment: @Dns Ah I see. Could you show me how you implement <myCustomTag>?