# Passing param using directive to child component angular

Tags: angular, typescript

i trying to create child component that can passing param using directive, but i still not found any tutorial to create itu.

i have try some from this :
[Get reference to a directive used in a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36345618/get-reference-to-a-directive-used-in-a-component)

here my code

This is the template from parent component

```
<child-component>
    <grand-child-directive [name]='Ghandy'></grand-child-directive >
    <grand-child-directive [name]='Ani'></grand-child-directive >
    <grand-child-directive [name]='Budi'></grand-child-directive >
</child-component>
```

this grand-child-directive directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'grand-child-directive ',
})
export class gc{
  @Input() name:string;
}
```

This is my child-component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  templateUrl: './child-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child-component.component.scss'],

})

export class childComponent implements OnInit 

@ViewChildren(gc) gc: gc;

  constructor(
  ) {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(gc.name)
  }
}
```

when i console.log gc.name, i got undefined, not array [Ghandy, Ani, Budi]

I would be glad for any help.

Comment: Why are you  projecting directive into component?

Comment: @Chellappan, i need to process the name ([Ghandy, Ani, Budi]) in child component, and besides the name, I also need something else like address

Comment: Why not using `@Input()` in the child-component?
[pass-data-to-child-component](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-passing-data-child-component/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use ContentChildren instead of ViewChildren. Then you should implement AfterContentInit lifecycle hook to access the value.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  templateUrl: './child-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child-component.component.scss'],

})

export class childComponent implements OnInit,AfterContentInit 

 @ContentChildren(GrandChildDirective) gc:QueryList<GrandChildDirective> ;

  constructor(
  ) {

  }
  ngAfterContentInit() {
     console.log(this.gc.toArray().map(item=>item.name));
  }
}
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-snd3at)