# How can i access my directive attached to the cchild omponent when calling

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have child component in my `App Component`. To that child component i have attached one directive.

```
<app-complete  autoCompletion #custom="autoCompletion"  [autocompleteOptions]="autocompleteOptions" (optionSelected)="addChip($event)"></app-complete>
```

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[autoCompletion]',
  exportAs: 'autoCompletion'
})
export class AutoCompleteDirective {
    @Input() autoCompletion;
}
```

If i  want to access that directive in my `App component` then i will do

**app.component.ts**

```
  @ViewChild('custom') custom: ElementRef;
  
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('custom', this.custom);
  }
```

but i can't find a way to do this directly in my child component.

I tried in `app.complete.ts` file

```
@ViewChild('custom') custom: ElementRef;
  
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('custom', this.custom);
  }
```

but i get printed undefined

Comment: Have you added  `directives:[autoCompletion],` in your  `app.component.ts`  ?

Comment: I have my directive added only in `app.module.ts` file so it is global.

Comment: Also , i can't add `directives` in component decorator

Comment: See this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36345618/get-reference-to-a-directive-used-in-a-component

Comment: I mean this one: `@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives:[MyCustomDirective],
    ...
})`

Comment: No, i can't add `directives` like that, try it also, there will be error