# How to get a reference to a directive used in the component?

Tags: angular

This is the template for the component:

```html
<cesium-viewer></cesium-viewer>
```

I created a custom directive for "cesium-viewer" called CesiumDirective. CesiumDirective was declared at NgModule. But I got this error when I tried to get the instance of my custom directive at the component:

```
main.ts:7 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[CesiumDirective -> CesiumDirective]:
```

This is a code block for the used component:

```js
@Component({
    selector: "app-root",
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private cesiumDirective: CesiumDirective) {}
}
```

What is wrong? I have already read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36345618/get-reference-to-a-directive-used-in-a-component).

Comment: The questions does not contains view child at all, could you please try to use view child and access the property on ngafterviewinit! components and directives are not accessed through the contructor usually!