# Jest test error of a directive bound to a template variable in a component template

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs

I have bound a directive to component on the template to call a directive method from the component. Everything is working but I have a problem with the test related to it. Here the process:

I use the exportAs directive property to then bind the directive into the component template

`numeric.directive.ts`:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[murCustomNumericFields]',
  exportAs: 'customNumericFieldsDirective',
})
export class CustomNumericFieldsDirective implements AfterContentInit, OnDestroy {
```

`component.html`:

```
 <six-input
     #directiveLinkReference="customNumericFieldsDirective" ....
```

Then from the component.ts file I use a `@ViewChild` to get the reference and fire a directive method inside component `setSkewNormValue` method after using `setValue` over a `formControl`.

`component.ts`:

```
@ViewChild('directiveLinkReference') directiveLinkReference: any;
```

...

```
setSkewNormValue(divisor: any, skew: any, form: FormGroup, skewNorm: string) {
    const skewNormFormControl = form?.get(skewNorm);
    if (!!divisor && !!skew) {
      const skewNormValue = Number(10 / (divisor * skew));

      skewNormFormControl?.setValue(skewNormValue)

      if (this.directiveLinkWithReference) {
        this.directiveLinkReference.applyDecimalPipeAccordingToLanguage();
      }
    } else {
      skewNormFormControl?.setValue('');
    }
  }
```

Then on my component jest test I got this error message.

> NG0301: Export of name 'customNumericFieldsDirective' not found!

I tried to import directive `CustomNumericFieldsDirective` into the `TestBed.configureTestingModule` like this:

`component.spec.ts`:

```
 beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        VolatilityActionComponent,
        CustomNumericFieldsDirective
      ],
```

but nothing.

Fellows, any idea?

Comment: possible to give a stackblitz with the issue replicated?