# What is ViewChild in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

From the official [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/ViewChild-var.html). A `ViewChild`:

```
Configures a view query.

View queries are set before the ngAfterViewInit callback is called.
```

The explanation is very minimal and I still don't quite understand what is it used for.

Consider this [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/78FjnOGEjE0g48JV1ebw?p=preview) from a blog I found.

Taking away the `@ViewChild(TodoInputCmp)` have no effect on the code inside `TodoInputCmp`

Can someone give me some insight?

Thanks

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326745/whats-the-difference-between-viewchild-and-contentchild

Comment: the [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/78FjnOGEjE0g48JV1ebw?p=preview) you mentioned has no effect just because someone forgot to remove unused code.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It provides a reference to elements or components in your view:

```
@Component({
  ...
  directives: [SomeComponent],
  template: `
  <div><span #myVar>xxx</span><div>
  <some-comp></some-comp>`
})
class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild('myVar') myVar:ElementRef;
  @ViewChild(SomeComponent) someComponent:SomeComponent;
  
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.myVar.nativeElement.innerHTML);
    console.log(this.someComponent);
  }
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** The variables are not initialized before `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: In Angular 8 , ViewChild takes 2 parameters 

`@ViewChild('myVar',  {static: false}) myVar:ElementRef;`

Answer (score 14):

The `ViewChild` decorator is used to gain access to a child component, found in the template, so that you can access its properties and methods.

Answer (score 11):

### `@viewchild()`

In Angular we define a template of a component by combining plain HTML with other Angular components. In the view (html file) we can define template reference variable in the following manner:

```
<input type="text" #firstNameInput>
<myDefaultComponent #reference></myDefaultComponent>
```

Using template reference variables the components and html elements are usually only available inside the view. However, when we want to inject references of the component or html element and inject them into our model (ts file component class) we can use `@viewchild()` in order to achieve this.

We use `@viewchild()` decorator in the following manner:

```
  @ViewChild('myReference') myClassproperty;
```

Using `@viewchild()` will do different things based on where the reference was placed:

1. When the reference was placed on a html component it will inject the **html DOM component** into the model as a class property (myClassproperty in this example). We then can access this property in the model using `this.myClassproperty`
2. When the reference was placed on a angular component it will inject the **Angular component** into the model as a class property (myClassproperty in this example). We then can access this property in the model using `this.myClassproperty`

Thus `@viewchild()` is very convenient to inject other child components or child HTML elements into the model class. The parent component now can react based on the behaviour of its child components and html elements which is a feature that is often required.

**Caveat:**

Also important to note is that you should put `@viewchild()` in an `ngAfterViewInit()` hook. This is because you can only have access to the elements in the view after they are rendered.

Comment: such an underrated answer!

Answer (score 8):

Angular have two parts one is the view and the other is component or the code which handles the view data & events. In component many times we would like to refer instance of view elements , that’s where “ViewChild” helps.

“ViewChild” helps to reference view objects in the component to which it is connected. “ViewChild” references one object while “ViewChildren” references collection.

For example in the below code at the left hand side we have view and the right hand side we have the component ( code behind) , you can see how viewchild is used to refer the view elements like Div1 , Comp2 and so on.

You can also check out this youtube video which explain [viewchild in angular](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZsaTJzke0iA) in more crisp way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@viewchild is used to display many component in tabs view . Using this method services of particular component will be called by individually.

**common.component.html**

```
  <li (click)='ageingTabClick("dailysummary")' ><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Daily Order Status</a>
```

Now make a new function after ngOnInit()  , 
like:
**landingPage.component.html**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initTab(); //call the init function
  }

  initTab(){
    this.getdata(); //calling of any function
  }
```

now come to main tabs component. 
**common.component.ts**

Now  declare .

```
  @ViewChild(landingPageComponent ) landingtab: landingPageComponent ;
```

```
ageingTabClick(_type) {  

    switch (_type) {
      case 'dailysummary':
        this.fttxjourneytab.initTab();
        break;


      default:
        break;
    }
```

Now start adding compoonent as much you want.