# can't have access to dom element in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using `Angular-cli`. I have:

```
<div id="show"></div>
```

and I need to have access this dom element in .ts file
something like `document.getElementById('show')` return me null

Comment: *I have div block with id="show"

Comment: use <div #show> ... and get the ElementRef with @ViewChild:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614284/what-is-viewchild-in-angular2

Comment: Generally you should be modifying the model, the view will get updated automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<div id="show">

constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#show');
}
```