# Why is the ViewChild undefined when outside of the component where it is called?

Tags: angular, dynamic, ref, viewchild, ng-template

I use in Angular the following in order to create a dynamic component:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appAdHost]'
})
export class AdHostDirective {

  constructor(public viewContainerRef:ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

ad.directive.ts is in the app.module. I call it like this from component a (module a):

```
@ViewChild(AdHostDirective) dlHost: AdHostDirective;

constructor(private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
this.dlHost.viewContainerRef.createComponent(
  this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(DyTwoComponent)
);
}
```

In component a.component.html I have added

```
<ng-template adHost></ng-template>
```

With this configuration everything works as expected. If I move

```
<ng-template adHost></ng-template>
```

outside of component a, to another component.html (in the same module or outside of the module) the

```
 @ViewChild(AdHostDirective) dlHost: AdHostDirective;
```

returns undefined in the console.

```
ERROR TypeError: can't access property "viewContainerRef", this.adHost is undefined
```

The structure of the project s as follows:

```
app.moodule
   a.module
   b.module
```

My wish is to be able to call the @ViewChild from a child module (a or b) but to have the template in the root module (app.module). I would be grateful if you could help me with some ideas how to achieve this. Thank you!

Comment: ViewChild, only get the "children" of a component -it's **not** like the document.getElementByClass of javaScript-, re-think your code using services or similar

Comment: Eliseo is totally correct. The issue has basically been dealt with in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36614284/what-is-viewchild-in-angular2, https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-viewchild/, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-viewchild-access-component. Basically you'll have to reapply your solution in each component, maybe have a basecomponent that takes this solution from which you can inherit. (extends from)