# Is there any way to store a html element inside a private variable in AngularJS 2?

Tags: angular

Im a newbie in angular 2. Im trying to avoid *ngFor loop coz I think it has problems with IE9 which is the minimum requirement for my project. I remember in ReactJS you can store elements/component inside a variable. Is this possible in Angular 2?

Comment: Did you tried ngFor because I haven't problem in IE?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to https://github.com/angular/angular you can check that Angular2 supports IE9, so you shouldn't have any issues.

Asking your question:

- DOM Elements: `ElementRef` class
- Components: `ComponentRef<T>` generic class

You have to use the following decorators to access the element/component in your template:

- ViewChild/ViewChildren
- ContentChild/ContentChildren

Check this to see the difference between ViewChild & ContentChild https://stackoverflow.com/a/34327754/6771029

Here is how to use the `@ViewChild` decorator https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html