# Can I 'observe' the dynamic children of a component?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-ngcontent

I have an application in which I compose forms using several form components. Now I want to create some kind of a foreign key field which lists the already existing objects and also shows an 'add' button. This button displays another form component in a modal dialog. That 'sub' form is simply displayed using `<ng-content>`. This all works perfectly

I'll illustrate the situation. This is the template of `<form-component>`:

```
<form class="form">
    <form-field>
        <another-form-component (save)="handleSave()"></another-form-component>
    </form-field>
</form>
```

The template of `<form-field>`:

```
<modal-dialog-component [(visible)]="showForm">
    <!--
        Here the <another-form-component> which was passed
        to <form-field> is added:
    -->
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</modal-dialog-component>
<div class="form-field">
    <select> <!-- existing options --> </select>
    <button (click)="openForm($event);">Create new</button>
</div>
```

As you can see `<another-form-component>` has an `@Output()` for it's `save` event. This is an `EventEmitter`.

My question is: How can I subscribe to this `EventEmitter` from the `<form-field>` component? I would like to know when the form is saved so I can close the `<modal-dialog>`.

Remember: The form is passed using `<ng-content>`. Can I use `@ViewChildren` to get the children of `<form-field>` and use some sort of `addEventListener()` method? Does something like that even exist?

Hope you can help me!

Greetings,
Johan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query [ContentChildren](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ContentChildren-decorator.html) from your `<form-field>` component class and subscribe to events they emit as following:

```
export class FormFieldComponent implements AfterContentInit {

    @ContentChildren(AnotherFormComponent) anotherFormComponents: QueryList<AnotherFormComponent>;

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        console.log('anotherFormComponents: ', this.anotherFormComponents.toArray());

        this.anotherFormComponents.toArray()[0].save.subscribe(valueEmitted => {
            console.log('Value emitted from the anotherFormComponents[0]: ', valueEmitted);
        });
    }
 }
```

[QueryList](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/QueryList-class.html#!#notifyOnChanges-anchor) gets updated whenever the `AnotherFormComponent` is added, removed, or moved. You can 'observe' the changes by subscribing to the `QueryList.changes` Observable:

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.anotherFormComponents.changes.subscribe(qList => {
        console.log('Changed list: ', qList);
    });
}
```

Btw, it's worth knowing: [What's the difference between @ViewChild and @ContentChild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326745/whats-the-difference-between-viewchild-and-contentchild)