# Use template in angular2

Tags: angular

I want to set dynamic template in my page, that I use  but info is limited.

Set `@Viewchild` and `@ContentChild` to assign `template` , that's a great example on web (i.e. light DOM and shadow DOM , [REF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326745/whats-the-difference-between-viewchild-and-contentchild)).

`ngOutletContext` and `ngTemplateOutlet`,however, are limited too.You can search `experiment` tag.Can someone please explain and somebody use `<template let-item>` .Is that the same way?

Comment: Please try to improve your question. What exactly is the problem? What is the expected behavior or outcome?

Comment: umm...I just want to know what is `ngOutletContext` and `ngTemplateOutlet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update Angular 5**

`ngOutletContext` was renamed to `ngTemplateOutletContext`

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-beta5-2017-08-29

**original**

You can create a template and then pass it around and `ngTemplateOutlet` allows to render such a template. `ngOutletContext` allows to pass data to the template.

`let-item` allows to reference the value passed as `$implicit`

```
<template #foo let-item>
  {{item}}
</template>

<template [ngTemplateOutlet]="foo" ngOutletContext="{$implicit: 'bar'}"></template>
```

or to use any other passed value

```
<template #foo let-item="bar">
  {{item}}
</template>

<template [ngTemplateOutlet]="foo" ngOutletContext="{bar: 'baz'}"></template>
```

Instead of using a template variable and referencing the template within the same component, you can also use `@ViewChild()` to get a reference of the template and pass it around to render the template in another component.

Comment: precisely explain!!thanks a lot . is any possible to use @contentChild when I use <template>?

Comment: Sure,  you can use that as well.