# Access @ViewChild template from ng-content

Tags: angular

Is it possible to use templates in combination with ng-content like described here:

app component:

```
<table-column>
  <template #template let-item="item">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.foo" />
  </template>
</table-column>
```

table-column component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'table-column',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class TableColumnComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('template') template;  

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.template); // undefined
    // create column object with template and different metadata...
  });      
}
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/x5ARRwpnJTfFAUr5Le5N?p=preview)?

The problem I get `undefined` using different life cycle hooks (ngOnInit, ngAfterViewInit)...

Comment: ContentChild and AfterContentInit?

Comment: Thanks! Works with ContentChild even with OnInit. You can create an answer - I will accept it.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you want to search within Light DOM then you need to use `@ContentChild` and wait until `ngAfterContentInit` hook

```
@ContentChild('template') template;  

ngAfterContentInit() {
  console.log(this.template);
}
```

See also

- [What's the difference between @ViewChild and @ContentChild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326745/whats-the-difference-between-viewchild-and-contentchild)

Comment: This must be one of the most amazing answers ever. It's incredibly short, yet contains absolutely everything necessary to access child-elements the Angular way (without using e.g. `document.getElementsByClass(...)`). Thank you so much!