# Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined ng-content in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a `my-alert-component` which looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-alert',
  template: `
    <h1 (click)="alert()">{{type}}</h1>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    `
})
export class MyAlertComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() type: string = "Success";

  alert(){
    console.log("alert");
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And in my `app` component, I am doing the following:

```
import { Component,ComponentRef,ComponentFactory,ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver,ChangeDetectorRef, ViewChild, TemplateRef, ViewChildren, QueryList, AfterViewInit,ElementRef, ContentChild, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyAlertComponent } from './my-alert.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <app-my-alert>
      <p #insideNgContentVar>A paragraph inside ng-content</p>
    </app-my-alert>
    <app-my-alert type="danger"></app-my-alert>
    <app-my-alert type="success"></app-my-alert>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChildren(MyAlertComponent) alertComponents : QueryList<AlertComponent>;
  @ContentChild('insideNgContentVar') insideNgContent:ElementRef;

  ngAfterContentInit(){
    console.log(this.insideNgContent.nativeElement.textContent);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.alertComponents.forEach((alertComponentInstance) => console.log(alertComponentInstance));
  }
}
```

This is pretty simple, I thought.

But the error I am getting is:

`EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined`

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

If in `my-alert-component` I do:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-alert',
  template: `
    <h1 (click)="alert()">{{type}}</h1>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    `
})
export class MyAlertComponent implements AfterContentInit,AfterViewInit {

  @Input() type: string = "Success";

  @ContentChild('insideNgContent') insideNgContentRef:ElementRef;

  alert(){
    console.log("alert");
  }

  ngAfterContentInit(){
    console.log(this.insideNgContentRef.nativeElement.textContent);
  }
```

And in my `app` component:

```
template: `
    <app-my-alert>
    </app-my-alert>
    <app-my-alert type="danger">
        <p #insideNgContent>A paragraph inside ng-content</p>
    </app-my-alert>
    <app-my-alert type="success"></app-my-alert>
  `
```

After these changes also, something seems to be missing.

What is that?

Comment: Have you tried hooks later in the oder? https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: @eddyP23 So I have tried in order right? ngAfterContentInit comes before ngAfterViewInit. I still don't know why it is not working.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should be using `@ViewChild` here, as per this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34327754/5018962

So basically, `ViewChild` is going to look for components in the DOM that are defined in your component's template, but `ContentChild` will look for components defined as `ng-content` of your `app-root` component itself, but not `ng-content` of some child components. But in this case no one is using your `app-root` component and no one is going to inject any DOM there, so that's why you get `undefined`

EDIT.

It would work, if you added the following line to the `app-my-alert` component:

```
@ContentChild('insideNgContentVar') insideNgContent:ElementRef;
```

because that means, look at what is defined in the `ng-content` of `app-my-alert`. Hope that sheds some light on this topic

Comment: But is not that wrong? I am accessing something from the projected content, and should not that be available in @ContentChild()?

Comment: `@ViewChild()` works. But Still why does not `@ContentChild()'? See the update pls. I have tried your changes. They totally make sense. But still, why am I getting the same error?

Comment: And as I tried to explained a few time. `@ViewChild` looks for stuff that you can literally see in the template of the component. `@ContentChild` is for stuff that you can't literally see in template, but will be injected as an `ng-component` when your component gets used

Comment: Ok. But as I understood I can still use the `ContentChild()` in my alert component. That's what you also pointed also.
So, even after that, in my edit, I am getting `Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined`.

Comment: It looks that it should work. I assume that you have seen this https://netbasal.com/understanding-viewchildren-contentchildren-and-querylist-in-angular-896b0c689f6e

Comment: Yes. I was following the examples. But I could not get it work. So I am stuck :(

Comment: If you provided more details like an error or something, that might help, because the syntax you provided looks alright. Also opening a new question might be a good idea, as now you have two separate questions mushed together