# ContentChild not working via QueryTemplate and Component reference

Tags: angular

I am able to project content but unable to get reference of the same

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khyr1u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

I tried using the #SelectorName and also via Using component name with
ContentChild() and ContentChildren().
Somehow I am unable to get reference despite calling in ngAfterViewInit hook

updated plunk illustrating : viewchild, viewchildren ,contentchild , contentChildren :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wnhayw?file=src/app/course-card/course-card.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `@ViewChild` decorator instead of the `@ContentChild` decorator.

The `@ContentChild` decorator provides you with a reference to an element that that is between the opening and closing tag of your component:

```
<my-component>
  <div #myContentChild></div>
</my-component>
```

The `@ViewChild` decorator provides you with a reference to an element that is within your component view:

**my-component.component.html:**

```
<div #myViewChild></div>
```

In your example, the `#test` element is a view-child of `my-app` and a content-child of `<app-course-card>`. That means that if you want to query `#test` from within the `AppComponent` component then you use `@ViewChild`. If you want to query `#test` from within `CourseCardComponent` then you need to use `@ContentChild`.

For further details see the following SO post:

[What's the difference between @ViewChild and @ContentChild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326745/whats-the-difference-between-viewchild-and-contentchild)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wnhayw?file=src/app/course-card/course-card.component.ts