# Angular 9 - Rendering a limited number of component's children

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components

I have a ButtonGroup component that will render a certain number of ButtonAction components. 
I tried to assign a template property (TemplateRef) to each ButtonAction, so that I can loop on and pass them to a ng-template (via *ngTemplateOutlet). 
 I directly inject TemplateRef into the constructor of ButtonAction, but I get the error *“No provider for TemplateRef”*. 
Since my aim is to render only a **limited number** of a component’s children, another solution I have found is to access the template via directive. But I don’t want to force our user to use the directive on each child. 
So, how can I do?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'button-group',
  template: `
    <div>
       <ng-content *ngIf="canDisplayAllChildren; else limitedChildren"></ng-content>

       <ng-template #limitedChildren>
         <ng-container *ngFor="let button of buttons">
           <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="button.template"></ng-template>
         </ng-container>
       </ng-template>

       <button-action (click)="toggle()" *ngIf="shouldLimitChildren">
         <icon [name]="'action-more-fill-vert'"></icon>
       </button-action>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class ButtonGroupComponent {
    @Input()
    public maxVisible: number;

    @ContentChildren(ButtonActionComponent) 
    public buttons: QueryList<ButtonActionComponent>;

    public isClosed: boolean = true;

    public toggle() {
        this.isClosed = !this.isClosed;
    }

    public get shouldLimitChildren() {
        return this.hasLimit && this.buttons.length > this.maxVisible;
    }

    public get canDisplayAllChildren() {
        return !this.shouldLimitChildren || this.isOpen;
    }   
}
```

Where ButtonActionComponent is:

```
@Component({
  selector: "button-action",
  template: `
    ...
  `
})
export class ButtonActionComponent {
    ...
  constructor(public element: ElementRef, public template: TemplateRef<any>) {}
}
```

Comment: If I'm not making any confusion, you can inject a TemplateRef only in directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me some time to come up with an ipothetical solution but I think I might have something useful that doesn't rely on explicit directive added to your component children.

Being unable to use `TemplateRef` without structural directives involved, I thought about a mechanism which is similar to the `React.cloneElement` API.

---

So, let's define a basic `ButtonComponent` that will be used as a children of the `ButtonGroupComponent`.

```js
// button.component.ts

import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-button",
  template: `
    <button>{{ text }}</button>
  `
})
export class ButtonComponent {
  @Input()
  public text: string;
}
```

---

The `GroupComponent` should do clone and append to its View only the number children specified via the `maxVisible` input property, which I also given a `POSITIVE_INFINITY` default value for cases when it isn't provided at all, allowing all children to be shown:

```js
// group.component.ts

...

@Input()
public maxVisible: number = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

...
```

Let's ask Angular to provide children given in our content (I would say that this is the best explanation of the difference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34327754/3359473):

```js
// group.component.ts

...

@ContentChildren(ButtonComponent)
private children: QueryList<ButtonComponent>;

...
```

We now need to let Angular inject a couple of things:

1. our current container where to manually instantiate children to;
2. a factory resolver that will help us creating components on the fly;

```js
// group.component.ts

...

constructor(
  private container: ViewContainerRef,
  private factoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
) {}

private factory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ButtonComponent);

...
```

Now that we have been given anything we need from Angular, we can intercept the content initialization implementing the `AfterContentInit` interface and adding the `ngAfterContentInit` lifecycle.

We need to cycle over our children, create new components on the fly and set all the public properties of the new components to the ones of the children given:

```js
// group.component.ts

...

ngAfterContentInit() {
  Promise.resolve().then(this.initChildren);
}

private initChildren = () => {
  // here we are converting the QueryList to an array
  this.children.toArray()

    // here we are taking only the elements we need to show
    .slice(0, this.maxVisible)

    // and for each child
    .forEach(child => {

      // we create the new component in the container injected
      // in the constructor the using the factory we created from
      // the resolver, also given by Angular in our constructor
      const component = this.container.createComponent(this.factory);

      // we clone all the properties from the user-given child
      // to the brand new component instance
      this.clonePropertiesFrom(child, component.instance);
    });
};

// nothing too fancy here, just cycling all the properties from
// one object and setting with the same values on another object
private clonePropertiesFrom(from: ButtonComponent, to: ButtonComponent) {
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(from).forEach(property => {
    to[property] = from[property];
  });
}

...
```

The complete `GroupComponent` should look like this:

```js
// group.component.ts

import {
  Component,
  ContentChildren,
  QueryList,
  AfterContentInit,
  ViewContainerRef,
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  Input
} from "@angular/core";
import { ButtonComponent } from "./button.component";

@Component({
  selector: "app-group",
  template: ``
})
export class GroupComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @Input()
  public maxVisible: number = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

  @ContentChildren(ButtonComponent)
  public children: QueryList<ButtonComponent>;

  constructor(
    private container: ViewContainerRef,
    private factoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) {}

  private factory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
    ButtonComponent
  );

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    Promise.resolve().then(this.initChildren);
  }

  private initChildren = () => {
    this.children
      .toArray()
      .slice(0, this.maxVisible)
      .forEach(child => {
        const component = this.container.createComponent(this.factory);
        this.clonePropertiesFrom(child, component.instance);
      });
  };

  private clonePropertiesFrom(from: ButtonComponent, to: ButtonComponent) {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(from).forEach(property => {
      to[property] = from[property];
    });
  }
}
```

---

Beware that we are creating the `ButtonComponent` at runtime, so we need to add it in the `entryComponents` array of the `AppModule` (here is the reference: https://angular.io/guide/entry-components).

```js
// app.module.ts

import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { ButtonComponent } from "./button.component";
import { GroupComponent } from "./group.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ButtonComponent, GroupComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [ButtonComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

---

With these two simple components, you should be able to render only a subset of the given children maintaining a very clear usage:

```html
<!-- app.component.html -->

<app-group [maxVisible]="3">
  <app-button [text]="'Button 1'"></app-button>
  <app-button [text]="'Button 2'"></app-button>
  <app-button [text]="'Button 3'"></app-button>
  <app-button [text]="'Button 4'"></app-button>
  <app-button [text]="'Button 5'"></app-button>
</app-group>
```

In this case, only the first, second and third children should be rendered.

---

The codesandbox I tested everything is this one:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-darkness-6zorf?file=/src/app/app.component.html

Hope this helps.